# MySQL Workbench 6.3.5 crashes when opening XAMPP MySQL local database

Tags: mysql, crash, mysql-workbench

I installed XAMPP for Windows (xampp-win32-5.6.14-4-VC11-installer) and am not able to open
mySQL database. Here are the versions:

XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2
MySQL Workbench 6.3.5

Doing a standard TCP/IP connection at 127.0.0.1 on port 3306
username: root
password: not set yet, it is blank

When I click on TEST CONNECTION the MySQL Workbench crashes:

**Edit**

It looks like this version is not compatible with MariaDB which is a forked version of MySQL I believe that XAMPP is using nowadays:

```
13:52:57 [INF][      Workbench]: UI is up
13:52:57 [INF][      Workbench]: Running the application
13:53:42 [INF][      SqlEditor]: Opened connection '' to mariadb.org binary distribution version 10.1.8-MariaDB
13:53:43 [INF][     AutoCCache]: Initializing autocompletion cache for Mysql@127.0.0.1_3306
13:53:43 [INF][          Admin]: Auto-created instance profile for connection 
13:53:43 [ERR][      WBContext]: Unsupported server version: mariadb.org binary distribution 10.1.8-MariaDB
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Is that reproducible all the time? Also check the log (C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log).

Comment: thanks that helped a lot. Log says: 13:53:42 [INF][      SqlEditor]: Opened connection '' to mariadb.org binary distribution version 10.1.8-MariaDB
13:53:43 [INF][     AutoCCache]: Initializing autocompletion cache for Mysql@127.0.0.1_3306
13:53:43 [INF][          Admin]: Auto-created instance profile for connection 
13:53:43 [ERR][      WBContext]: Unsupported server version: mariadb.org binary distribution 10.1.8-MariaDB

Comment: Ah right, MySQL Workbench really only supports MySQL. In the next version this will be shown more prominently.