# What is the difference between MySQL and MariaDB database?

Tags: mysql, xampp, relational-database, mariadb

I have been using XAMPP for a long time and was surprised that XAMPP has switched to MariaDB from MySQL.

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

How will this change impact on existing developers using MySQL? For example, can existing development tools for MySQL work seamlessly with MariaDB? What are notable difference between MySQL and MariaDB that developers need to take note?

I am not sure if it is advisable to upgrade XAMPP version because of this database change. I am worried of the migration of data from MySQL to MariaDB.

Comment: shouldn't be a problem. but you should test your application with the new environment anyways. https://mariadb.com/kb/de/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Comment: As I type into the Google search box _MySQL mariadb_ even before I complete the second word the autocomplete function comes up with _MySQL mariadb comparison_ as the first option.

Comment: knowing the difference in features in one thing. Knowing how they will impact on development during migration is another. For the latter, I think experts on stackoverflow may help.

Comment: A duplicate from the programmer section: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/whats-the-difference-between-mariadb-and-mysql

Comment: There are probably no differences that you will 'notice'.  MariaDB has a lot of extra features.  But, until you use any of them, you won't see a difference.  Well...  There are differences in the optimizer.  So, some complex queries may run slower or faster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376109/mysql-workbench-incompatible-nonstandard-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For example, can existing development tools for MySQL work seamlessly with MariaDB?"

A common development tool for MySQL is MySQL Workbench.  MySQL Workbench may not support MariaDB.

See this: [MySQL Workbench 6.3.5 crashes when opening XAMPP MySQL local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927871/mysql-workbench-6-3-5-crashes-when-opening-xampp-mysql-local-database)

Another one here: [MySQL Workbench incompatible/nonstandard server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376109/mysql-workbench-incompatible-nonstandard-server/)

Having said that, there are other options to MySQL Workbench (a good alternative is [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) for example, which works great by the way with the local MariaDB install by XAMPP).

But all of this is minor I believe, for the most part the move to MariaDB is painless and you won't notice any difference.  The great thing is that there always seems to be good information online about anything you might run into anyway.  I wouldn't worry much at all about "the migration of data from MySQL to MariaDB."

(Curious if user1824987 made the move and if so if they found any way they were impacted by it.)

Comment: I worked with MySQL workbench on Maria. No problem at all except for some warning message.