# What exactly is the difference between MySQL and MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

The previous versions of XAMPP would include MySQL. Now they include MariaDB.
I used to use the previous versions but now I upgraded XAMPP and it has MariaDB.

So what exactly is the difference between them? Or are they both similar?

What changes should I make in my programming approach?

Should I switch over to the previous version?

Comment: mariadb is a fork of mysql. they're generally interchangeable, but they're not 100% the same anymore. mysql's owned by oracle, mariadb is under development by some of the original mysql people who didn't go to oracle, or since left.

Comment: What do you mean by mariadb is a fork of mysql?

Comment: The code in the two "forks" is not identical.  Each has some new features.  You are _unlikely_ to see a difference between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between MySQL and MariaDB database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151652/what-is-the-difference-between-mysql-and-mariadb-database)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/):

> Until MariaDB 5.5, MariaDB versions functioned as a "drop-in replacement" for the equivalent MySQL version, with some limitations. From MariaDB 10.0, it is usually still very easy to upgrade from MySQL.
>
> [...]
>
> This means that for many cases, you can just uninstall MySQL and install MariaDB and you are good to go. There is not generally any need to convert any data files.

Note also that according to the same documentation page:

> However, the implementation differences continue to grow in each new MariaDB version.

To know the exact differences between MySQL and MariaDB versions, see the specific pages in the documentation:

- [Incompatibilities and Feature Differences Between MariaDB 10.5 and MySQL 8.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-105-and-mysql-80/)
- [Incompatibilities between MariaDB 10.4 and MySQL 8.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-104-and-mysql-80/)
- [Incompatibilities between MariaDB 10.3 and MySQL 5.7](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-103-and-mysql-57/)
- [Incompatibilities between MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 5.7](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-102-and-mysql-57/)

You can also check [this answer on Software Engineering Stack Exchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/120224)